# Converting class-based component to functional is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert my class-based component to functional but I don't know how to pass 2 things in one onClick function without using set state. I also don't want to make 4 extra functions because that would defeat readability.

I've tried putting it all in one arrow function.

```
function Calculator() {


const [form, setForm] = useState({
    firstNum: '',
    secondNum: ''
})
const [Sum, setSum] = useState('')
const [isSubmitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)
const [Operator, setOperator] = useState(null)





function handleOperator() {
    const f = [firstNum]
    const l = [secondNum]
    const Plus = f + l
    const Minus = f - l
    const Multiply = f * l
    const Divide = f / l
    switch (Operator) {
        case 'plus':
            return setSum(Plus), setSubmitted(false)
        case 'minus':
            return setSum(Minus), setSubmitted(false)
        case 'multiply':
            return setSum(Multiply), setSubmitted(false)
        case 'divide':
            return setSum(Divide), setSubmitted(false)
        default:
            return null
    }
}

function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value, type } = event.target
    if (type === 'text') {
        setForm({
            form,
            [name]: value
        })
    }

}

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    setSubmitted(true)
}


return (
    <div>
        <p>{isSubmitted === true && Sum}</p>
        <button name="Plus" onClick={() => setOperator('plus'), handleOperator}>+</button>
        <button name="Minus" onClick={() => setOperator('minus'), handleOperator}> -</button >
        <button name="Multiply" onClick={() => setOperator('multiply'), handleOperator}>*</button>
        <button name="Divide" onClick={() => setOperator('divide'), handleOperator}>/</button>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input name="firstNum" type="text" value={firstNum} onChange={handleChange} />
            <input name="secondNum" type="text" value={secondNum} onChange={handleChange} />
            <br />
            <button> = </button>
        </form>

    </div >
)
```

}

export default Calculator

The result is supposed to be you type in the first and second numbers, then you click your operator and then you click the equal sign and it should give you your answer.

Comment: what are you trying to do with `handleOperator`?  It is not invoked at the moment.

Comment: Can you share the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do 2 things in an inline arrow function:

```
<button name="Plus" onClick={() => { setOperator('plus'); handleOperator(); }}>+</button>
```

You just need to give the arrow function a body `{...}` and invoke the `handleOperator` function.